# How svm.svm_predict_probability method (for return type) works?

Tags: machine-learning, return-value, svm, libsvm

think that we have two categories with a lots of documents that some of them are in the first category and the others are in the second category , i got the model of categories successfully ,and as you know the `svm.svm_predict_probability` method  returns `1 or -1`

i want to know that when it returns `1` and when it returns `-1` and how can i find that which number assigned to the first category and which one of them assigned to the second category

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [libsvm FAQ](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f430):

> Internally class labels are ordered by their first occurrence in the
>   training set. For a k-class data, internally labels are 0, ..., k-1,
>   and each two-class SVM considers pair (i, j) with i < j. Then class i
>   is treated as positive (+1) and j as negative (-1). For example, if
>   the data set has labels +5/+10 and +10 appears first, then internally
>   the +5 versus +10 SVM problem has +10 as positive (+1) and +5 as
>   negative (-1).
>
> By this setting, if you have labels +1 and -1, it's possible that
>   internally they correspond to -1 and +1, respectively. Some new users
>   have been confused about this, so after version 3.17, if the data set
>   has only two labels +1 and -1, internally we ensure +1 to be before
>   -1. Then class +1 is always treated as positive in the SVM problem. Note that this is for two-class data only.

So in modern libsvm (after 3.17) there are two cases:

- If you have +1 and -1 clases in your training data, than it is the same in the model
- Otherwise, first class that appears in the training data is the +1 class, and the second one is -1 one

The internal decision is maked based on the specific formulation of the SVM problem, which can be shortly stated as:

`f(x) = sgn( SUM_i alpha_i y_i K(SV_i,x) + b )`

where

- alpha_i - lagragian coefficients found during optimization procedure (for i'th Support vector)
- y_i - label of i'th support vector
- SV_i - i'th support vector
- b - intercept/bias value (found during optimization)
- K(.,.) - kernel function used in training, for example linear kernel K(x,y) = x'y, or rbf Kernel K(x,y) = exp(-gamma ||x-y||^2 )